# How do I prove this statement?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I have to prove that if $$u=t^{\lambda}y(z)$$ and $$z=\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}} \,\,,$$ then $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}=\frac{\partial ^{2}{u}}{\partial{x}^{2}} \Rightarrow y''_{zz}+\frac{1}{2}zy'_z-\lambda y=0$$

What would be, at least, the right direction in which I should think while solving this problem?

Comment: Is $u$ a function of $\lambda , t,x$ or just a function of $t,x$?

Comment: That's the most ridiculous part, I haven't been given any other conditions, explanations etc.

Comment: I guess $\lambda$ would be a constant

Comment: I am assuming $\lambda$ is a constant, but that's just intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\delta{u}}{\delta{t}} = \lambda\cdot t^{\lambda - 1}\cdot y + t^{\lambda}\cdot y_{z}'\cdot \dfrac{-x}{2}\cdot t^{-\frac{3}{2}}$, and

$\dfrac{\delta^2{u}}{\delta{x}^2} = \dfrac{\delta}{\delta{x}}\left(t^{\lambda}\cdot y_{z}'\cdot t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right) = t^{\lambda}\cdot t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot y_{z}''\cdot t^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Thus:

$\dfrac{\lambda\cdot y\cdot t^{\lambda}}{t} - \dfrac{t^{\lambda}\cdot z\cdot y_{z}'}{2t} = \dfrac{t^{\lambda}\cdot y_{z}''}{t}$, and the answer follows from this equation by dividing both sides by $\dfrac{t^{\lambda}}{t}$